# Selenium webdriver service option error

Tags: vb.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When run my project, I encountered

> Chromedriver.exer not found error
>
> "OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException" to do resolve this error

I inserted `Application.StartupPath` as Chromedriver's value

but here have another problem because I also want to hide console window

but if I input `Application.startupPath` I can't insert service command option.

```
    Dim driver As IWebDriver = Nothing
    Dim opt As New ChromeOptions
    opt.AddArgument("--headless")
    opt.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Browser, LogLevel.All)
    opt.AddUserProfilePreference("""profile.managed_default_content_settings.images""", 2)
    Dim service As ChromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(Application.StartupPath)
    service.HideCommandPromptWindow = True
    driver = new ChromeDriver(Application.StartupPath, opt)
```

Comment: did you install the chromedriver.exe file and put into the project structure ?

Comment: yes..i installed selenium webdriver and what exact mean put into project structure? sorry

Comment: you need to put "chromedriver.exe" file in your project folder

Comment: sure i already put inside my project folder